# Evaluate the multiplier field variable of the environment

Tags: variables, azure-devops, release-management, multi-configuration

I try Something like in vsts release management:

- Define variable a with  : 1,2,3
- Define variable b with  : 4,5,6
- Define variable c with  : $(a),$(b)
- Use variable c in field Multiplier when i use environment Multi-configuration parallelism capability.

Result : 2 times environments deployed : $(a) and $(b)
I want deploy 6 times the envoironment : 1,2,3,4,5 and 6

An Idea to workaround ?

In a build task the variable $(c) is expanded and value is : 1,2,3,4,5,6   ... I don't uderstand why field "Multiplier" not expand the variable

Comment: Why don't you define a variable with 1,2,3,4,5,6? Then it will deploy 6 times.

Comment: We have more than 100 servers and the list of the servers consists of several lists, by site geographical. 
Deployments use the complete list, others use a partial list. Without aggregation of lists, it is very difficult to maintain

Comment: You may submit the user voice.

Answer (score 2):

You should use variables `a` and `b` separate by comma (**`a,b`**) for Multipliers option.

[image]

Only the variables you specifies in Multipliers option, the variables values will be act as a multiplier. So if you use `a,b` for Multipliers option, values from variable `a` and variable `b` will be multiplied as `1,4`, `1,5`, `1,6`, `2,4`, `2,5`, `2,6`, `3,4`, `3,5` and `3,6` (deploy 9 times).

If you use only one variable `c` for Multipliers option, vsts only deploy the values (separate by comma) from variable `c` separately. So as you found, it only deploy two times as `$(a)` and `$(b)`.

More details, you can also find the examples in [Parallel and multiple execution using agent phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/phases#parallel-and-multiple-execution-using-agent-phases).

Comment: Thank you for the reformulation, we agree on the diagnosis. By cons it does not advance me. Is there a way to merge the variables used by the Multipliers field? maybe with the "output variable feature" (one phase set variable and second phase consume variable) in preview ?

Comment: Nope, variables can only be Multiplied by specifying them in Muti-configration Multipliers option and separate by comma for now.